# Storing in variable vs. having multiple different methods

Tags: java, variables, switch-statement, bytecode

What are the pros and cons of using this:

```
String a = new String();
switch (i) {
case 1: a = "Cueck"; break;
case 2: a = "Blub"; break;
case 3: a = "Writing cases is BORING!"; break;
}
System.out.println(a);
```

Versus:

```
switch (i) {
case 1: System.out.println("Cueck"); break;
case 2: System.out.println("Blub"); break;
case 3: System.out.println("Writing cases is BORING!"); break;
}
```

Which generates better bytecode? And which generates more bytecode?

Comment: i suggest you to get ASM bytecode outline and test it yourself. :)

Comment: The first one stores the result in a variable.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it unless its getting executed 42 billion times... Is this question just for theory, or for a real problem?

Comment: I would suggest you to use second approach, since there are only 3 `String` literal created, where as in the first one, there are 4 `String` objects

Comment: This two programs don't have the same behaviour for isntance, with i=0)

Comment: It would recommend you remove the `= new String()` from your top example and add a default case in your switch statement.

Comment: Use the `javap` tool (in the JDK) to disassemble it and look into the bytecode. But really, the reason to choose for one or the other shouldn't depend in the first place on what bytecode is produced. Readable and maintainable source code is more important.

Comment: @DuncanJones it was just for an example. I'm actually setting JSONObjects in the switch statement and have a default. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `javap -c classname` you can check the bytecode yourself,

Here's option 1:

(Note, I had to initialise `a = null` otherwise it doesn't compile)

```
   7:   aconst_null
   8:   astore_2
   9:   iload_1
   10:  tableswitch{ //1 to 3
                1: 36;
                2: 42;
                3: 48;
                default: 51 }
   36:  ldc     #3; //String Cueck
   38:  astore_2
   39:  goto    51
   42:  ldc     #4; //String Blub
   44:  astore_2
   45:  goto    51
   48:  ldc     #5; //String Writing cases is BORING!
   50:  astore_2
   51:  getstatic       #6; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   54:  aload_2
   55:  invokevirtual   #7; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   58:  return
```

Here's option 2:

```
   7:   iload_1
   8:   tableswitch{ //1 to 3
                1: 36;
                2: 47;
                3: 58;
                default: 66 }
   36:  getstatic       #3; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   39:  ldc     #4; //String Cueck
   41:  invokevirtual   #5; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   44:  goto    66
   47:  getstatic       #3; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   50:  ldc     #6; //String Blub
   52:  invokevirtual   #5; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   55:  goto    66
   58:  getstatic       #3; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   61:  ldc     #7; //String Writing cases is BORING!
   63:  invokevirtual   #5; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   66:  return
```

Personally, I don't think there's better bytecode in this instance, I find option 1 more readable.

Answer (score 5):

Your first option is neater and has less redundant code. One suggested change:

```
String a;

switch (i) {
  case 1: a = "Cueck"; break;
  case 2: a = "Blub"; break;
  case 3: a = "Writing cases is BORING!"; break;
  default: throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown option!");
}

System.out.println(a);
```

Don't create a String unnecessarily - `a` should be instatiated when required. A default case should either throw an exception or set `a` to a default value.

> Which generates better bytecode? And which generates more bytecode?

I wouldn't worry about that. This doesn't strike me as a likely bottleneck in any real-life application. Also, you cannot be sure what the JVM will do to optimise the byte-code once your application is running.

Comment: Also never call `new String()` as this messes with [String interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning).

Comment: @bmorris591 Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: I merely meant that if you call the constructor directly the `String` is not interned, from the [spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html) only "compile time constant" `String`s are interned.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there will be much difference in bytecode size but I suggest first approach. If you in some future code changes decide not to call `System.out.println(a)` but `logger.debug(a)` you will change that only on one place and not on all `case` switches.